# Applied mirror effect, want to UV paint without mirroring, but it still mirrors

Tags: uv, texture-painting, mirror, mirror-modifier

I'm having issues with UV painting without it mirroring the image. I wanted to mirror a section of the object, so I drew that section and applied the mirror modifier so it would work individually. However, I also wanted to paint an assymetrical section on that object, and I can't because it's not working individually on the UV paint function (it keeps mirroring). What can I do so part of the painting is mirrored but the other section isn't?

Comment: We're going to need more information.

Comment: Your UVMap is still mirrored. You have to Unwrap the mesh again.